# Unable to choose src for github.io portfolio page

Tags: reactjs, github

[image]

For the main git repository, devanshdalal.github.io, I am unable to choose the src branch to use for deploying, github.com always picks up the master branch. It becomes difficult now, because I now have to push my `build/` forlder to master. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently github doesn't support choosing custom folder for repo named like `{GITUSER}.github.io` -
From [community help post](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Pages/Can-I-define-a-custom-source-or-folder-from-which-my-site-hosted/td-p/100)

> From https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/, the only three options that GitHub Pages recognizes are:
>
> - master branch
> - docs/ folder on the master branch
> - gh-pages branch

But for repo like `{GITUSER}.github.io`, having `docs/` folder also doesn't work(I couldn't make it work). I faced this similar issue a while back. I was using `jekyll` to build the static pages for my site. I know It's really frustrating, but as of now what you want, is not possible.

However, I made a workaround to `version-control` my `jekyll` project as well the generated static `github.io` pages.

I maintain a separate repo for the `jekyll` version of the project(which in your case I guess would be the `react` project). So locally I have two separate repo -

- `{my_username}.github.io` - > which will contain the static pages, and remote for this local repo would be the `{my_username}.gihub.io` repo(the static site repo).
- I also have a separate repo for the `jekyll` project. Which has a different remote repo setup. I configured settings for this project in such way that after build, the static pages will be saved in the local repo of `{my_username}.github.io` folder. then I can just commit and push separately in the two repos.

This way I can keep track of the static pages as well as the `jekyll` project that builds the static pages.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make sure that before you configure a publishing source, the branch or folder you want to use as your publishing source already exists in your repository.

This link [GithubPages](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) will solve your problem.

Comment: no, for normal repos, that is the case, but for the repo named `{GITUSER}.github.io` page, github always deploys from the master, there is no way to choose src for this repo. I am using `gh-pages -d build public -b master`. as a hack for now. @Cauchy